# Only Open Folds With z Commands

Tags: folding

If I navigate the first line of a folded function with `h`,`l`, etc it will open the fold. Navigating search matches with `n` will also open a fold if there is a match inside the fold.

Can you configure folds to only open when you explicitly open them with `z` commands?

Comment: No. You can't. Vim handling of folds if utterly broken. Even if you set `foldopen=` there's bunch of keys that will "nicely" open the fold for you. For example `c-o` in insert mode when on the folded line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the [`'foldopen'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27foldopen%27) option to control which commands or movements will open folds.

The specific cases you mentioned:

- `h` or `l`: these are horizontal movements, controlled by the `hor` setting.
- search or `n`: these are controlled by the `search` setting.

So you might want to remove these two specific cases, which you can do with:

```
set foldopen-=hor foldopen-=search
```

Or maybe you want to disable all of them and just set `'foldopen'` to be empty:

```
set foldopen=
```